# Update ViewPager after Asynctask from the result

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I had a problem here.

I have a login_activity that execute asynctask to get some result from a php file which it connects to mysql database.

```
public class login_main extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataSendToActivity{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String type = "getProfileImages";

        RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData(this);

        retrieveData.execute(type);

        //After Asycntask, get the result and put back into image array

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(login_main.this,image);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void sendData(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = obj.getString("image"+i);
                image.add("http://192.168.12.252/"+id+"/profile.png");
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When i get the result i try to process the result by using interface from the asynctask

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);
}
```

Everything is working fine except that the image array always empty when i pass it to the PageAdapter. How can i pass the data back to activity from asycntask and push into the array image, by using interface, it cant work.

Or anyway i can directly process it in Asyntask and update the ViewPager.

Here is my Asynctask

```
public class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    Context context;
    RetrieveData(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    private OnDataSendToActivity dataSendToActivity;

    public RetrieveData(Activity activity){
        dataSendToActivity = (OnDataSendToActivity)activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String profile_url = "http://192.168.12.252/getprofile.php";
        String image_url = "http://192.168.12.252/imagelist.php";
        String type = params[0];

        if(type.equals("getProfile")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                URL url = new URL(profile_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = null;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(type.equals("getProfileImages")){
            try {
                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Image", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("Image", "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = null;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `AsyncTask` here?

Comment: check if you are getting any exception or not and also check length of `result` in `sendData()`. You might be getting some `JSONException` or length of `result` as 0

Comment: @RaviRupareliya the result had something inside and it is the thing i want. As you can see i did a loop there to add the string into the array. When i Log.d the array, there is 3 string inside the array, however when it backs to the viewpager, the image got nothing

Comment: did u get the output? @ChongWaiLun

Comment: @Roy Everything was working fine from the Asynctask to the sendData, but the problem is i cant pass the image into the viewpage after processing in the sendData, when i try to Log.d the image array in sendData, there is something. But when it goes back to onCreate the image array is empty. I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution sequence is all messed up. by the time ur adding data to ur image array the,the empty image array has already been passed to the view pager adapter,therfore ur image array is empty.

u continue to do the same thing but instead of setting view pager adapter in onCreate() set the adapter after u call the method sendData();

modify the sendData() method like this.

```
  public void sendData(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = obj.getString("image"+i);
                image.add("http://192.168.12.252/"+id+"/profile.png");
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     adapter = new CustomAdapter(login_main.this,image);//set ur image array here
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had try this before, but the ViewPager go crazy. When i try to slide to the left for second image, it always go back to the first one. It seems like this part keep on looping and it always set it to image 1

Comment: share ur view pager adapter code definitely there is an error in ur adapter..@ChongWaiLun

Comment: You are right! there is something wrong there that cause the problem. It is working now, thanks!

Comment: you should set the adapter once and then use notifydatasetchanged on yout adapter instead of calling setAdapter each time in setData mehod.